# Make Browsers Remember Passwords For Different Sections of Site?

Tags: html, forms, autofill

The site I am working on right now has three different login forms depending on who you are. (Admin section, user section, different user section.) These, of course, have different usernames and passwords.

As a developer of the site, I am constantly switching between the different sections of our sites using different logins. This causes my browser to remember the password from one section and auto-fill it for the other sections.

How can I make my browser remember one user/pass combo for one section and a different one for a different section? Is it possible to design the HTML forms (or even .htaccess) to cause this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question what I do at work for something similar is use a different browser for a couple different sections that we have (Chrome/FF/IE).  Allows me to save a login for the site and then I just use whatever browser is needed when I'm looking at a specific section.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about login using web server security, setting a different realm on each section should force the browser to present the user with another popup window.

In Apache, this is done with `AuthName`

For regular forms that are autofilled by your browser, one thing you can try is by giving the username and password fields a different name. If this fails, I'm afraid the only option is to disable auto-complete altogether, for which you should be able to find many references by just searching.

Comment: No, I'm using a basic HTML form. The problem is that my browser sees a username and password field and assumes I want to fill it with the stuff from last session.